# return one row for each customer mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how I print one row for each customer. Right now when I run

```
SELECT email_address, sum(quantity * item_price), sum(discount_amount * quantity)
FROM customers JOIN order_items
ORDER BY sum(quantity * item_price)
```

I only get the very first customer. Everything turns out correct as far as prices go, but it only prints the first customer. I need all the customers in the table. Any suggestions? Do I need to join any of the tables? It seems to be working without the joining of the tables. Oh also I need it to be in descending order based on the item_price. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: add group by before order by also read docs first before using aggregate functions [**`GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: when I add group by email_address I get all the customers but now I just get the same sum for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT email_address, sum(quantity * item_price), sum(discount_amount * quantity)
FROM customers JOIN order_items on customers.id= order_items.id
GROUP BY (email_address)
ORDER BY sum(quantity * item_price)
```

Comment: the issue that i'm having right now is trying to figure out how to properly joint these tables. customers has customer_id, order_items has order_id, and orders has order_id and customer_id. should i join orders with customers and then join order_items with that table?\

Comment: @kevorski:- Yes you can join them like that!

Answer (score 0):

you can get it within array using loop

```
$query ="SELECT email_address, sum(quantity * item_price), sum(discount_amount * quantity)
         FROM customers JOIN order_items
ORDER BY sum(quantity * item_price)";

$records=$mysql_query($link,$query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ecord))

{

print_r($row);

}
```